# How do I read an XML with unknown structure

Tags: c#, xml

I'm coding an XML viewer for a school assignment but I don't have any clue how I can load XML-files without knowing the structure of the file.
I'll display the XML structure in a listbox after I've read the file.

It's a school assignment and This should be the result :
[image: XML Viewer]

I have an example file that I can load perfectly but I'm stuck with a random file.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
using(XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("c:\\temp\\sites.xml"))
{          
   //Load file
   doc.Load(xmlReader);
   XmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;

   foreach (XmlNode siteNode in root)
   {
      //Nodes
      XmlNode URLNode = siteNode.FirstChild;
      XmlNode EmailNode = siteNode.LastChild;

      //Create site
      Site site = new Site(URLNode.FirstChild.Value, EmailNode.FirstChild.Value);

      //Add to list
      sites.Add(site);
  }
  Console.WriteLine(sites.Count);
}
```

Comment: But what do you want to do? If you want to display node names with/without attributes, you don't need to know the structure. You simply iterate through the file and output the data you're after.

Comment: It looks like you're already making assumptions about the structure/content of the XML that you're reading?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not going to be able to turn the XML data into known classes (like your `Site`) class without knowing something about the structure, as you'd need some way to migrate the data to the class constructor parameters/properties/etc.

That being said, if you just want to view or inspect the XML file itself, you can just recursively inspect the XmlNode elements inside the root element.

[XmlNode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.aspx) includes all of the properties you'd need to do this, such as [ChildNodes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.childnodes.aspx), [Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.attributes.aspx), and [Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.value.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the use case but while writing a small job scheduler, I represented each job as a set of 3 things - a scheduler, a fully qualified class name implementing a particular job, some textual job context (XML). When a scheduler needed to execute a job at scheduled time, while it was creating a job class using reflection and known location of the assemblies, it passed XML context to a job constructor, which knew how to deal with it.

Similarly if it's possible for you to define a class *within* the XML, then you can read it first and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If it's only a viewer, why not just load the XML into a DataSet or DataTable and then bind it to a DataGrid

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd try using LINQ to XML, with emphasis on the functionality provided by [XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx) - it's friendlier and easier imo. I also recommend that you use recursion (as Reed Copsey suggested) to traverse your XML.